Why does `dispatch_queue_t appear` as `OS_dispatch_queue_concurrent in LLDB?
Creating a concurrent queue:
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.demo.concurrentQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

When I use LLDB to debug and print concurrentQueue:
po concurrentQueue

The output is:
<OS_dispatch_queue_concurrent: com.demo.concurrentQueue[0x600001ee8200] = { xref = 1, ref = 1, sref = 1, target = com.apple.root.default-qos[0x1000c4340], width = 0xffe, state = 0x0000041000000000, in-flight = 0}>

From the return value of the dispatch_queue_create function, it seems that concurrentQueue should be of type dispatch_queue_t structure. Why does LLDB print concurrentQueue as OS_dispatch_queue_concurrent? What exactly is OS_dispatch_queue_concurrent?
To find the answer, I looked at the source code of libdispatch:
dispatch_queue_t
dispatch_queue_create(const char *label, dispatch_queue_attr_t attr)
{
    return _dispatch_lane_create_with_target(label, attr,
            DISPATCH_TARGET_QUEUE_DEFAULT, true);
}

static dispatch_queue_t
_dispatch_lane_create_with_target(const char *label, dispatch_queue_attr_t dqa,
        dispatch_queue_t tq, bool legacy)
{
    dispatch_queue_attr_info_t dqai = _dispatch_queue_attr_to_info(dqa);

    //
    // Step 1: Normalize arguments (qos, overcommit, tq)
    //

    dispatch_qos_t qos = dqai.dqai_qos;
#if !HAVE_PTHREAD_WORKQUEUE_QOS
    if (qos == DISPATCH_QOS_USER_INTERACTIVE) {
        dqai.dqai_qos = qos = DISPATCH_QOS_USER_INITIATED;
    }
    if (qos == DISPATCH_QOS_MAINTENANCE) {
        dqai.dqai_qos = qos = DISPATCH_QOS_BACKGROUND;
    }
#endif // !HAVE_PTHREAD_WORKQUEUE_QOS

    _dispatch_queue_attr_overcommit_t overcommit = dqai.dqai_overcommit;
    if (overcommit != _dispatch_queue_attr_overcommit_unspecified && tq) {
        if (tq->do_targetq) {
            DISPATCH_CLIENT_CRASH(tq, "Cannot specify both overcommit and "
                    "a non-global target queue");
        }
    }

    if (tq && dx_type(tq) == DISPATCH_QUEUE_GLOBAL_ROOT_TYPE) {
        // Handle discrepancies between attr and target queue, attributes win
        if (overcommit == _dispatch_queue_attr_overcommit_unspecified) {
            if (tq->dq_priority & DISPATCH_PRIORITY_FLAG_OVERCOMMIT) {
                overcommit = _dispatch_queue_attr_overcommit_enabled;
            } else {
                overcommit = _dispatch_queue_attr_overcommit_disabled;
            }
        }
        if (qos == DISPATCH_QOS_UNSPECIFIED) {
            qos = _dispatch_priority_qos(tq->dq_priority);
        }
        tq = NULL;
    } else if (tq && _dispatch_queue_is_cooperative(tq)) {
        DISPATCH_CLIENT_CRASH(tq, "Cannot target object to cooperative root queue - not implemented");
    } else if (tq && !tq->do_targetq) {
        // target is a pthread or runloop root queue, setting QoS or overcommit
        // is disallowed
        if (overcommit != _dispatch_queue_attr_overcommit_unspecified) {
            DISPATCH_CLIENT_CRASH(tq, "Cannot specify an overcommit attribute "
                    "and use this kind of target queue");
        }
    } else {
        if (overcommit == _dispatch_queue_attr_overcommit_unspecified) {
            // Serial queues default to overcommit!
            overcommit = dqai.dqai_concurrent ?
                    _dispatch_queue_attr_overcommit_disabled :
                    _dispatch_queue_attr_overcommit_enabled;
        }
    }
    if (!tq) {
        uintptr_t flags = (overcommit == _dispatch_queue_attr_overcommit_enabled) ? DISPATCH_QUEUE_OVERCOMMIT : 0;
        tq = _dispatch_get_root_queue(
                qos == DISPATCH_QOS_UNSPECIFIED ? DISPATCH_QOS_DEFAULT : qos,
                    flags)->_as_dq;
        if (unlikely(!tq)) {
            DISPATCH_CLIENT_CRASH(qos, "Invalid queue attribute");
        }
    }

    //
    // Step 2: Initialize the queue
    //

    if (legacy) {
        // if any of these attributes is specified, use non legacy classes
        if (dqai.dqai_inactive || dqai.dqai_autorelease_frequency) {
            legacy = false;
        }
    }

    const void *vtable;
    dispatch_queue_flags_t dqf = legacy ? DQF_MUTABLE : 0;
    if (dqai.dqai_concurrent) {
        vtable = DISPATCH_VTABLE(queue_concurrent);
    } else {
        vtable = DISPATCH_VTABLE(queue_serial);
    }
    switch (dqai.dqai_autorelease_frequency) {
    case DISPATCH_AUTORELEASE_FREQUENCY_NEVER:
        dqf |= DQF_AUTORELEASE_NEVER;
        break;
    case DISPATCH_AUTORELEASE_FREQUENCY_WORK_ITEM:
        dqf |= DQF_AUTORELEASE_ALWAYS;
        break;
    }
    if (label) {
        const char *tmp = _dispatch_strdup_if_mutable(label);
        if (tmp != label) {
            dqf |= DQF_LABEL_NEEDS_FREE;
            label = tmp;
        }
    }

    dispatch_lane_t dq = _dispatch_object_alloc(vtable,
            sizeof(struct dispatch_lane_s));
    _dispatch_queue_init(dq, dqf, dqai.dqai_concurrent ?
            DISPATCH_QUEUE_WIDTH_MAX : 1, DISPATCH_QUEUE_ROLE_INNER |
            (dqai.dqai_inactive ? DISPATCH_QUEUE_INACTIVE : 0));

    dq->dq_label = label;
    dq->dq_priority = _dispatch_priority_make((dispatch_qos_t)dqai.dqai_qos,
            dqai.dqai_relpri);
    if (overcommit == _dispatch_queue_attr_overcommit_enabled) {
        dq->dq_priority |= DISPATCH_PRIORITY_FLAG_OVERCOMMIT;
    }
    if (!dqai.dqai_inactive) {
        _dispatch_queue_priority_inherit_from_target(dq, tq);
        _dispatch_lane_inherit_wlh_from_target(dq, tq);
    }
    _dispatch_retain(tq);
    dq->do_targetq = tq;
    _dispatch_object_debug(dq, "%s", __func__);
    return _dispatch_trace_queue_create(dq)._dq;
}

I looked at the source code and couldn't find how concurrentQueue becomes OS_dispatch_queue_concurrent. Does anyone know the principle behind this transformation?

Um. Polymorphism? The returned object can be any concrete implementation of the interface defined by dispatch_queue_t

This sort of stuff happens all the time. Try NSString *foo = @"bar"; and then in lldb, do p foo and it will say (__NSCFConstantString *) 0x0000000102134038 @"bar". It is not a NSString, but a __NSCFConstantString. (This is a slightly different issue, but the basic idea still applies.) Bottom line, don’t worry about the specific internal types being returned. In the frameworks, there are all sorts of internal types being returned, but they enjoy the same interfaces and features of the type you used in your code.
